# Error while creating view for FullCalendar

Tags: views, javascript

I've installed the FullCalendar module in a Drupal 7.28 installation (a clean sandbox with nothing except dependencies for FullCalendar).

Following the instructions [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1237808), I'm trying to create a view for the calendar, but when I try to add a field (*Content: Post date*, as it shows in the instructions), upon clicking Apply, I get set to: /admin/structure/views/ajax/add-item/calendar_view_test_/page/field with a screen full of junk

```
[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"seven","theme_token":"Jzga71J3eqY_4IiPQChia5Z0N-jWV9v4QLfKNnXuKpw"},"CTools":{"dependent":{"edit-options-label":{"values":{"edit-options-custom-label":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-element-label-colon":{"values":{"edit-options-custom-label":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-custom-date-format":{"values":{"edit-options-date-format":["custom","raw time ago","time ago","today time ago","raw time hence","time hence","raw time span","time span","raw time span","inverse time span","time span"]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-second-date-format":{"values":{"edit-options-date-format":["today time ago"]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-second-date-format-custom":{"values":{"edit-options-second-date-format":["custom"]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-timezone":{"values":{"edit-options-date-format":["custom","long","medium","short"]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-element-type":{"values":{"edit-options-element-type-enable":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-element-class-enable":{"values":{"edit-options-element-type-enable":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-element-class":{"values":{"edit-options-element-class-enable":[1],"edit-options-element-type-enable":[1]},"num":2,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-element-label-type":{"values":{"edit-options-element-label-type-enable":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-element-label-class-enable":{"values":{"edit-options-element-label-type-enable":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-element-label-class":{"values":{"edit-options-element-label-class-enable":[1],"edit-options-element-label-type-enable":[1]},"num":2,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-element-wrapper-type":{"values":{"edit-options-element-wrapper-type-enable":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-element-wrapper-class-enable":{"values":{"edit-options-element-wrapper-type-enable":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-element-wrapper-class":{"values":{"edit-options-element-wrapper-class-enable":[1],"edit-options-element-wrapper-type-enable":[1]},"num":2,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-text":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-alter-text":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-path":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-make-link":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-absolute":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-make-link":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-replace-spaces":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-make-link":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-external":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-make-link":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-path-case":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-make-link":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-link-class":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-make-link":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-alt":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-make-link":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-rel":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-make-link":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-prefix":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-make-link":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-suffix":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-make-link":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-target":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-make-link":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-help":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-make-link":[1],"edit-options-alter-alter-text":[1],"edit-options-alter-more-link":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-max-length":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-trim":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-word-boundary":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-trim":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-ellipsis":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-trim":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-more-link":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-trim":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-more-link-text":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-trim":[1],"edit-options-alter-more-link":[1]},"num":2,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-more-link-path":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-trim":[1],"edit-options-alter-more-link":[1]},"num":2,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-html":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-trim":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"},"edit-options-alter-preserve-tags":{"values":{"edit-options-alter-strip-tags":[1]},"num":1,"type":"hide"}}},"states":{"#edit-options-second-date-format-custom":{"visible":{"#edit-options-date-format":{"value":"today time ago"},"#edit-options-second-date-format":{"value":"custom"}}}}},"merge":true},{"command":"viewsSetForm","output":"\u003Cform action=\u0022\/admin\/structure\/views\/ajax\/add-item\/calendar_view_test_\/page\/field\u0022 method=\u0022post\u0022 id=\u0022views-ui-config-item-form\u0022 accept-charset=\u0022UTF-8\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-override clearfix container-inline\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-item form-type-select form-item-override-dropdown\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Clabel for=\u0022edit-override-dropdown\u0022\u003EFor \u003C\/label\u003E\n \u003Cselect id=\u0022edit-override-dropdown\u0022 name=\u0022override[dropdown]\u0022 class=\u0022form-select\u0022\u003E\u003Coption value=\u0022default\u0022\u003EAll displays\u003C\/option\u003E\u003Coption value=\u0022page\u0022\u003EThis page (override)\u003C\/option\u003E\u003C\/select\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022scroll form-wrapper\u0022 id=\u0022edit-options\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-item description form-wrapper\u0022 id=\u0022edit-options-form-description\u0022\u003EThe date the content was posted.\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-options-custom-label\u0022\u003E\n \u003Cinput
```

Anyone know the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when I said I was "following the instructions" that turned out to be not entirely true.  I just discovered that I was using a 2.x version of the library, despite the [warning](https://www.drupal.org/node/1056742) to not.  Once I downgraded to a 1.x version, everything worked as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously issues with this module. Install jQuery update, set it to 1.10. Create the view, then save it without the date. Add the date and now it works. However, views does not like jQuery 1.10 (or 1.9) and to prevent other issues you have to fall back to jQuery 1.8. Hence you are now in a catch-22. Solution - post an issue in the queue or use another calendar module.